# SoapUI with HTTP

Tags: soapui

I am about to test a web service using SoapUI.I do not have WSDL(Web Service Description Language) of the Web service.I need to test it through HTTP service.How and To which extent can I test? (I've been through SoapUI.org, but unable to find answer). 
I appreciate your time.

Comment: If you don't have WSDL, how do you know what to send? If you know exactly what to send, you don't need SoapUI, any HTTP client will do the trick, including [taG:curl].

Answer (score 0):

We can test the web service using SoapUI without having WSDL file.
We need the URL (ServiceEndPoint) and the XML block of the services...
U need to create HTTP Test Request for this and then enter the ServiceEndPoint URL and then give the required data in the XML block of HTTP Test request step and run the test.

Please try this....